# How to show the results of this query based on the title of the quiz?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name.....
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut, DivisionName 
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, IsSent, Description
UserQuiz Table: UserQuizID, QuizID, DateTimeComplete, Score, Username
```

***(IsSent is a flag that refers to the quiz that has been sent to all employees)***

I have the following query that retreives the title of the quiz that has been sent and the total number of participants in each division. The query works well but there is a minor error in it. The retrieved results will be displayed starting from the last sent quiz. The title of quizzes is like Quiz 12, Quiz 11 and Quiz 10. Now, the query shows me that (Quiz 9) is the last quiz. However, the last quiz has been sent is (Quiz 12).

**So how to modify this query to get the correct results?**

The query:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Total Number of Participants], dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.Title
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode
WHERE     (dbo.Quiz.IsSent = 1)
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.Title
ORDER BY dbo.Quiz.Title DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by Title, and the title is a varchar. "Quiz 11" comes before "Quiz 9" when ordered alphabetically since "1" and "11" comes before "9".

Now, I'm not sure about how you populate your QuizID value, but if it's an auto-populated integer, it might be better to use

```
ORDER BY dbo.Quiz.QuizID DESC
```

instead.

Better yet, add a CreatedDate in the Quiz table and sort by that column instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I also posted my answer here simultaneously with you.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I guess the ID is an int indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got my answer after million of tries. The solution is very simple:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Total Number of Participants], dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.Title
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode
WHERE     (dbo.Quiz.IsSent = 1)
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.Title, dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID
ORDER BY dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID DESC
```